# "dotnet run" command behaves differently than running in Visual Stuido 2017

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

So, the main problem is CORS:

I have a little API in `Net Core 2.1`, and a Angular `7` App. When I run the API in Visual Studio 2017 the CORS Policy **works fine**, but when I run it with `"dotnet run"` the typical `CORS` error appears in the browser.

I already set the "Development" environment whit:

```
setx ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT "Development"
```

This is the CORS Configuration in Startup.cs

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseCors(x => x
                .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials());
        }
```

Is Visual Studio 2017 doing something that I'm missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For specifying `Development` under `dotnet run`, try to run command below:

```
D:\xx\TestPro\TestPro\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2>set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
```

And then, run

```
D:\xx\TestPro\TestPro\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2>dotnet TestPro.dll
```

For `setx ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT "Development"`, it will not work for the current running command window, which means that after you run this command in the first `cmd.exe windows`, you need to start a new window to run `dotnet`.

Reference: [setx#remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/setx#remarks)

> Setx writes variables to the master environment in the registry.
>   Variables set with setx variables are available in future command
>   windows only, not in the current command window.

Comment: Still not working, I set the environment variable in the "netcoreapp2. 1" folder, I close the cmd window, and start a new one, but nothing. Also, I reset my computer.

I remember that the project was created in Visual Studio 2017, and not with "dotnet new"

Comment: @FernándezBortolasMatías After running the `dotnet` command, did you get `Development` or `Production` environment output in the console window?